# Unit testing my login component : "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')"

Tags: angular

hello guys i am new to the angular. Please notify where i have missed or committed mistake. As I am unit testing the Login component.

Here is the "**loginservice.ts**"

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
 public loginStatusSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  static generateToken: any;
  static getCurrentUser: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public getCurrentUser(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8010/current-user");
  }

  public generateToken(loginData:any){
   return this.http.post("http://localhost:8010/generate-token",loginData);
  }
   //login user: to set up token in local storage
   public loginUser(token){
       localStorage.setItem('token', token);
       return true;
   }
  //isLogin: user is logged in or not
  public isLoggedIn(){
    let tokenStr = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(tokenStr == undefined || tokenStr == '' || tokenStr==null)
    {
      return false;
    } else {

      return true;
    }
  }

  //logout: remove toke from local storage
  public logout()
  {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    return true;
  }

  //get token
  public getToken(): string{
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  //set user in local storage
  public setUser(user): void
  {
    localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  //get user
  public getUser()
  {
    let userStr = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if(userStr!=null)
    {
      return JSON.parse(userStr);
    }
    else {
      this.logout();
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  //get user role
  public getUserRole()
  {
    let user = this.getUser();
    return user.authorities[0].authority;
  }
}
```

Here is "**my login.component.ts**"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from 'services/login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 
loginData={
  username:'',
  password:'',
 };

 constructor(private snack:MatSnackBar,private loginService:LoginService,private router:Router){}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  

  login(){
    console.log("User btn clicked");

    if( this.loginData.password.trim()==''||this.loginData.password==null)
    {
      this.snack.open('password is required','',{
        duration:3000,
      });
      return;
    }
    // request to generate token from which we can access another apis using this token.
    this.loginService.generateToken(this.loginData).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{ 
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
        //login ...

       this.loginService.loginUser(data.token);
       this.loginService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
       (user)=>{
        this.loginService.setUser(user);
        console.log(user);
      //redirect:ADMIN dashboard
      //redirect : USER dashboard
      if(this.loginService.getUserRole()=="ADMIN")
      {//admin dashboard
        //window.location.href="/admin";
        this.router.navigate(['admin']);
        this.loginService.loginStatusSubject.next(true);

      }else if(this.loginService.getUserRole()=="USER")
      {//user dashboard
        //window.location.href="/user";
        this.router.navigate(['user']);
        //user subscribes it and sends notification after giving data
        this.loginService.loginStatusSubject.next(true);
      }else
      {
        this.loginService.logout();
      }
     }
    );

      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log('error!!');
       console.log(error);
       this.snack.open("Invalid Details!! Try again",'',{
        duration:3000,
       });
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Here is my testing component code :**login.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginService } from 'services/login.service';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let loginService: LoginService;
  let router: Router;
  let snackBar: MatSnackBar;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    loginService= jasmine.createSpyObj('LoginService', ['generateToken', 'loginUser', 'getCurrentUser', 'setUser', 'getUserRole', 'logout']) ;
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports:[MatFormFieldModule,FormsModule,HttpClientTestingModule,MatInputModule,BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: LoginService, useValue: loginService },
        { provide: Router, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']) },
        { provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('MatSnackBar', ['open']) }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents().then(()=>{
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      loginService = TestBed.inject(LoginService);
      router = TestBed.inject(Router);
      snackBar = TestBed.inject(MatSnackBar);
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  });


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('#login', () => {
    it('should show an error message if the password is empty or null', () => {
      component.loginData.password = '';
      component.login();
      expect(snackBar.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('password is required', '', { duration: 3000 });
    });

    it('should generate a token and log in the user if the password is not empty or null', () => {
      component.loginData.password = 'password';
      component.loginData.username='myadmin';
      component.login();
     loginService.generateToken(component.loginData);
      expect(loginService.getToken).toEqual('token');
      expect(loginService.generateToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component.loginData);
      expect(loginService.loginUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith('token');
      expect(loginService.getCurrentUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(loginService.setUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['admin']);
   });
  });

});
```

Here is my "login.component.html"

```
<div class="bootstrap-wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="container text-center">
                    <img src="../../../assets/CTSH-82a8444b.png" width="100" height="100"  style="vertical-align:middle">
                </div>
            
                <h3 class="text-center"> Login Here!!</h3>
                <form (ngSubmit)="login()">
                    <mat-form-field class ="full-width" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" 
                        [(ngModel)]= "loginData.username"
                        name="username" 
                         placeholder="Enter username" required>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="register.user.$dirty && register.user.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="register.user.$error.required"></span>
                            <mat-hint>Valid username please</mat-hint>
                            </span>
                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field class ="full-width" appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput
                        [(ngModel)]= "loginData.password"
                        type="password" 
                        name="password" 
                        placeholder="Enter password" required>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="register.user.$dirty && register.user.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="register.user.$error.required"></span>
                           
                            </span>
                      </mat-form-field>  
                      <div class="container">
                        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
                        <button mat-raised-button style="margin-left:10px">Reset</button>
                      </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My code is running normally, able to login . As i am unit testing it in Karma, is showing the error which is mentioned in title.
Please let me know guys. as i m stuck for couple days. It would be great help

Comment: Which line exactly throws? When your error throws it'll include the file name and line number to pinpoint this

Comment: @AndrewAllen from this line in "LoginComponent.ts" :: ================================================== this.loginService.generateToken(this.loginData).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{ 
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
        //login ...                                                     
       this.loginService.loginUser(data.token);
       this.loginService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
       (user)=>{
        this.loginService.setUser(user);
        console.log(user);

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what exactly is causing the error, reading the headline and looking at your `LoginService`, I assume that in your test file (`login.component.spec.ts`), you need to return an actual Observable for `getCurrentUser()` and `generateToken()`.

You could try using jest's mock functions and make sure that the mocked function returns a stream. For more, take a look here: https://webtips.dev/webtips/jest/mock-function-return-values

Example:
`jest.spyOn(TestBed.inject(LoginService), 'getCurrentUser').mockReturnValue(of( // your observable here ))`

Comment: from this line it was pinpointing the error in "loginComponent.ts" :                                            this.loginService.generateToken(this.loginData).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{ 
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
        //login ... ===================================================                 one thing strange is when i ran this in vscode,"subscribe" word was strikethrough when i was calling the function and other "subscirbe " wasnt strikethrough

Comment: Then it looks like you need to return an Observable for `generateToken()` in your testing file. You could try using the jest mock approach I mentioned above.